# Data is not Showing from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

My Database contains Hotel names, which i want to retrieve it but not showing their names.
such as Hotels->ID(created by Realtime Database)->Hotel Name.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQYo9.jpg)

i want to display their names also.

Comment: I can share my code if anybodies wants

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" Also see [Building a minimal repro](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.